# Как добавить класс и удалить его?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Как при клике на ссылку добавить класс и удалить его?

```js
$(".link").click(function() {
  $(".block").addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  background: black;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">Ссылка</div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: вместо `addClass` -> `toggleClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".link").click(function() {
  $(".block").toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  background: black;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">Ссылка</div>
<div class="block"></div>
```